# VueJS: Reference static file from public/index.html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am hardcoding meta og tags into public/index.html as I'm making a single page app. I can't find a way to reference the image from the assets though.

Is it possible to achieve this ? Otherwise I'll just upload it to strapi and have the backend server serve the file.
The next step is to use Nuxt.js to have the website as static files so I'm not really eager to use back-end server to serve the image.

Comment: you could upload your image to your public folder. Where is your favicon? This place would also work.

Comment: You can refer to images from the template `<img src="@/assets/images/home.png"/>`

Comment: `<img src="@/assets/images/home.png"/>` doesn't work in public/html

Comment: I dont know why I haven't though about putting it with favicon in public folder, will probably work !